# Checking container, with dragula drag and drop, for correct answer

Tags: javascript

I'm making a simple game, based on drag'n'drop, using dragula (https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula). I want to move some containers, and if they are in correct order trigger an event sucess, if not event fail, but I don't have any idea how to check the container with answer every time something is droped in there. I was looking in dragula options, but I don't see anything. I'm trying to use only JavaScript. Do you have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add id or some attribute for the drop containers and then you have to store the id in the array or object , each time you drop you have to check with the answers. this way help to find the correct answers.